# GPIO Python Checking to see if an input state has changed

Tags: python, gpio

Good evening all,

Please see code below. Is there anyway once inputs 23 & 24 and output 4 have been activated I can continuously check to see if any of the inputs have become false and if so send output 4 high?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

B.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,0)
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(4,1)


while True:
    if(GPIO.input(23) ==1):
        print("UP")
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)

    if(GPIO.input(23) ==0):
        print("DOWN")
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(2)

    input_state = GPIO.input(24) and GPIO.input(23)
    if input_state == True:
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
```

Comment: Yes of course, it’s just logic.You are trying to implement a ‘state machine’ - this can respond differently to the same input in each state. In your case you could have a `state` variable which is 0 for the non-23/24 state, and 1 for the 23&24 state. Then each time round the loop you have an if which does different things for each state. One important thing is you should probably read the inputs just once at the start of each loop, into variables, then test the variables. This makes the statemachine easier to debug because you can print the variable values and they won’t change until next loop

Comment: There are many ways of implementing a state machine. Try something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the schematic and/or what you're trying to do with the circuit, i won't really be able to improve the code. but this should work:

```
import pigpio, time

Debounce = 0.02

Input23 = 23
Input24 = 24

Output18 = 18
Output4 = 4

pi_GPIO = pigpio.pi()

pi_GPIO.set_mode(Input23, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_pull_up_down(Input23 , pigpio.PUD_UP)

pi_GPIO.set_mode(Input24, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_pull_up_down(Input24 , pigpio.PUD_UP)

pi_GPIO.set_mode(Output18, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_pull_up_down(Output18, pigpio.PUD_UP)

pi_GPIO.set_mode(Output4, pigpio.OUTPUT)


def cbf(gpio, level, tick):
    time.sleep(Debounce) # only used if using a button or any mechanical switch. Change value according to the type of switch, see datasheet and/or experimentation
    if pi_GPIO.read(Input23):
        print("Input23 UP")
        pi_GPIO.write(Output18, 0)

    else:
        print("Input23 DOWN")
        pi_GPIO.write(Output18, 0)


cb = pi_GPIO.callback(Input23, pigpio.FALLING_EDGE, cbf)


while True:
    if pi_GPIO.read(Input24) and pi_GPIO.read(Input23):
        time.sleep(Debounce) # only used if using a button or any mechanical switch. Change value according to the type of switch, see datasheet and/or experimentation
        if pi_GPIO.read(Input24) and pi_GPIO.read(Input23):  # only used if using a button or any mechanical switch. Change value according to the type of switch, see datasheet and/or experimentation
            pi_GPIO.write(Output4, 0)
```

The function CBF will be called whenever there's a change in the value, independent of the while loop.

You will need to install pigpio if you don't have it already. a more full-featured RPi.GPIO library that also supports remote access if enabled on the pi device.

```
pip install pigpio
```

Let me know if there are any more details you can provide.

Comment: Analog or digital signals? Above is for digital.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work so far. This will most likely change as I add more hardware into the system.

```
import pigpio, time

Debounce = 0.5

Input23 = 23
Input24 = 24

Output18 = 18
Output4 = 4

pi_GPIO = pigpio.pi()

pi_GPIO.set_mode(Input23, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_pull_up_down(Input23 , pigpio.PUD_UP)
pi_GPIO.set_mode(Input24, pigpio.INPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_pull_up_down(Input24 , pigpio.PUD_UP)
pi_GPIO.set_mode(Output18, pigpio.OUTPUT)
pi_GPIO.set_mode(Output4, pigpio.OUTPUT)

while True:

    if pi_GPIO.read(Input23):
        pi_GPIO.write(18, 0)
        print("ON")
        time.sleep(Debounce)
    else:
        pi_GPIO.read(Input23)
        pi_GPIO.write(18, 1)
        print("OFF")
        time.sleep(Debounce)

    if pi_GPIO.read(Input24) and pi_GPIO.read(Input23):
        pi_GPIO.write(4, 0)
        print("Green")
        time.sleep(Debounce)
    else:
        pi_GPIO.read(Input24)
        pi_GPIO.write(4, 1)
        print("Red")
        time.sleep(Debounce)
```